# How to keep all columns after groupby and averaging a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'data':

```
     USER  VALUE VALUE2
0    XOXO     21    AAA
1   ABC-1      2    BBB
2  ABC-1B      4    CCC
3   ABC-2      4    DDD
4  ABC-2B      6    EEE
5    PEPE     12    FFF
```

I run this through some code to combine similar names:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'USER':['XOXO','ABC-1','ABC-1B','ABC-2','ABC-2B', 'PEPE'], 'VALUE':[21,2,4,4,6,12], 'VALUE2':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE', 'FFF']})
data.USER = data.USER.str.replace('(-\d)B', r"\1")
data = data.groupby('USER', as_index=False, sort=False).VALUE.mean()
```

However I end up with a dataframe like so with VALUE2 dropped:

```
    USER  VALUE
0   XOXO     21
1  ABC-1      3
2  ABC-2      5
3   PEPE     12
```

How can I modify the code to preserve VALUE2 by keeping VALUE2 from the original USER? So VALUE2 of USER 'ABC-1' would be kept 'BBB' and 'DDD' for 'ABC-2'

```
    USER  VALUE   VALUE2
0   XOXO     21      AAA
1  ABC-1      3      BBB
2  ABC-2      5      DDD
3   PEPE     12      FFF
```

Comment: aggregate `VALUE` by mean and `VALUE2` by `first`

Comment: How do you decide whether to use `BBB` for user `ABC-1` and not `CCC`?

Comment: Groupby `USER` after stripping trailing `B` to get mean of `VALUE`. Appropriate combination of boolean selection  should eliminate unwated `VALUE2`. See below

Comment: @stackoverflow does this help? :-)?

Answer (score 1):

Groupby `USER` after removing the trailing B. Then use `.str.contains()` and `.isin()` to achieve appropriate boolean selection and filter final datframe

```
  df['VALUE']=df[['USER', 'VALUE', 'VALUE2']].groupby(df.USER.str.split('(?<=[1-2])(B)').str[0])['VALUE'].transform('mean')
   df[~((df.USER.str.contains('ABC'))&(~df.VALUE2.isin(['BBB','DDD'])))]

      
        USER  VALUE VALUE2
    0   XOXO     21    AAA
    1  ABC-1      3    BBB
    3  ABC-2      5    DDD
    5   PEPE     12    FFF
```

**How it Works**

```
#Strip trailing B in USER
df.USER=df.USER.str.split('(?<=[1-2])(B)').str[0]

    USER  VALUE VALUE2
0   XOXO     21    AAA
1  ABC-1      2    BBB
2  ABC-1      4    CCC
3  ABC-2      4    DDD
4  ABC-2      6    EEE
5   PEPE     12    FFF
```

#Find mean VALUE using groupby transform

```
df['VALUE']=df.groupby(df.USER.str.split('(?<=[1-2])(B)').str[0])['VALUE'].transform('mean')
print(df)

USER  VALUE VALUE2
0   XOXO     21    AAA
1  ABC-1      3    BBB
2  ABC-1      3    CCC
3  ABC-2      5    DDD
4  ABC-2      5    EEE
5   PEPE     12    FFF
```

#Boolean select anything containing `ABC`; `(df.USER.str.contains('ABC'))` and which does not have `BBB` and `DDD`; `(~df.VALUE2.isin(['BBB','DDD']))`

#Combine the two selections and then reverse the selection using `~`

```
~((df.USER.str.contains('ABC'))&(~df.VALUE2.isin(['BBB','DDD'])))
```

#Finally filter dataframe

Comment: Thanks @G. Anderson, corrected. Mean included.

Comment: have not gotten the chance to run your solution but by looking at `df[~((df.USER.str.contains('ABC'))&(~df.VALUE2.isin(['BBB','DDD'])))]`
it appears to be hard coded? I was looking for a way to preserve VALUE2 from the USER we 'combine into'. Say USERS XXX-1 and XXX-1T have VALUE2 EEE and TTT respectively. After combining the USER would be XXX-1 with VALUE2 EEE